# What is the reference count for the object returned by [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]

Tags: objective-c

What is the reference count of `temporaryDictionary` after this statement is executed:

```
temporaryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

We know that the reference count for `temporaryDictionary` is `1` if `temporaryDictionary` is initialized this way:

```
temporaryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Thank you :D

Comment: We don't know, and we don't need to know it either.

Comment: Hi @H2CO3, I want to know that reference count because I'm not sure I could manually release `temporaryDictionary` before the end of autorelease pool, by calling, for example, `self.temporaryDictionary = nil;`

Comment: its always safe to give `self.temporaryDictionary=nil` irrespective of the `retaincount` value

Comment: @Ishank but there is a `[_temporaryDictionary release];` in the setter implementation, given property attributes `nonatomic` and `retain`, so doesn't it have to be at least `1` reference count?

Comment: The implementation takes care of that...

Comment: @congliu `NSDictionary` retains the values and copies the keys. It will thus increase the reference count for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both statement the reference count is 1 (but do not count on it :))  and with ARC both statements produce the same result.

If ARC is not enabled than in the first statement the dictionary will be auto-released for you while in the second statement you are responsible for the release.

As @H2CO3 and Ishank implied you do not want to base your code on the reference count of an object as it might be changed by inner implementations you are not aware of.

Comment: http://www.whentouseretaincount.com has details and links to all the ways `retainCount` is useless.

Answer (score 1):

`temporaryDictionary`  is in `auotorelese pool`, so the `retain count` can be `1` at some time and `0` at some another point of time..

And yes, its never recommended to rely on `retainCount` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
temporaryDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Is in Autoreleased mode, no need to release manually.

```
temporaryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

You need to take care, in the block or in the dealloc(which ever is applicable) you are required to send `release`.

**In both the cases retain count will increase by 1, as Values are retained.**

**Now you have Automatic Reference Counting, so no need to worry about retain counts and your overhead to release it manually.*